gnu-tools-for-stm32 change after version 9 including non required module and consuming RAM
I inherited an STM32 project at work which was initially built with the version 9 quarter 2 GNU compiler and newlib nano libraries. The processor only has 16K RAM and this overflows on build with libraries version 10 and later.  The overflow is caused by the inclusion of the findfp.o module in the linking.
I did some investigation of the map files and something changed between versions 9 and 10 of the libraries so that findfp.o is now included in the linker output.
Further investigation showed me that findfp.o is actually referenced in version 10, but version 9 compiler seems to remove unreferenced RAM in the linking stage as I found version 10 had no more RAM usage in the libraries but more in the application code.  It looks like version 9 compiler / linker removed initialised but not used static RAM locations.  I tried the options -ffunction-sections and --data-sections but this made no difference. If there is another compiler option I can try, that would be helpful.
I also checked the selected options in STM32CubeIDE and found that "Discard Unused Sections ("-Wl,--gc-sections)", "Place Functions in their own sections (-ffunction-sections)" and "Place data in their own sections (-fdata-sections)" are all enabled.
Version 12 adds __sf to findfp.c, __sf is an array of 3 FILE structures and chews up 323 bytes of RAM.
#ifdef _REENT_GLOBAL_STDIO_STREAMS __FILE __sf[3]; #endif
RAM is very tight for this project and if possible, I want to know how I can get compiler to optimise out the unreferenced RAM like 9 did.  Not sure there is anything I can do about the __sf array
I can get the project to work by using the Fixed toolchain 9-2020-q2-update, but it would be good to be able to use the latest so that I can make use of any fixes / improvements.

Use the linker's cross reference to find out what other modules reference symbols of the module findfp, and recursively trace back to your sources. A look into findfp's source might also be helpful to find hints why it is included. What library are you using, newlib? (Please [edit] your question to add new information, do not add a comment.)

Projects created with CubeIDE will discard unused functions and data using the -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections compiler options. If you're not already using those, that might be a quick solution.

@pmacfarlane Does this help in case of a ready-made provided library like here? I'm sure that only referenced and as such used parts of a library are linked into the executable. However, for the OP's code it shall work.

@thebusybee Hmmm, that's a good point, not sure. Things like the HAL etc get built from source with your chosen options, but a pre-built library probably not. They should probably do it anyway and see if it makes a difference, it can't do any harm.

I tried adding those options to compiler and also to linker and there was no change to code generation . The option -WI was rejected and it suggested did you mean -W. The option --gc-sections was rejected and it suggested did you mean --data-sections

@BarryAndrews It would be -Wl,--gc-sections if you passed this option to gcc. It would just be --gc-sections if you were passing it directly to the linker (ld).

@BarryAndrews There is a comma and no space between -Wl and --gc-sections. -Wl means "use the following parts separated by commas as options to the linker."

Passing --sort-common --sort-section=alignment to the linker might squeeze you a few more bytes, but don't expect a miracle.

Are you sure __sf is really making it into your executable? I checked in a project I had open, and that symbol is listed in the map file as part of the "Discarded input sections". Running nm on the elf file also shows it is not present.

Had the same problem and I finally (frustrated) removed findfp.o and fwalk.o from libc_nano I'm using to get rid of it since I'm not using any libc-stdio.
arm-none-eabi-ar.exe -d libc_nano.a libc_a-findfp.o libc_a-fwalk.o (same for libg_nano.a if needed) for GCC >= 10
or in your  you can do s.th like this:
find . -name lib[cg]_nano.a -exec bin\arm-none-eabi-ar.exe -d {} libc_a-findfp.o libc_a-fwalk.o ;

@pmacfarlane - I used Amap to look at the RAM variables in the final linked exe and __sf is definitely there and its size makes sense with respect to the linker saying that there is insufficient room for the heap. I changed the liker file to say there was 18k RAM instead of 16K, just to allow it to link and see what was in the final output. Then I changed back to 16k for correct build.

@HS2 Don't you think that would be a good answer? How are references to the functions inside these modules resolved?

When I stumbled over the surprisingly increased image and RAM size starting with GCC10 newlib based bare-metal toolchain I tried a number of things to find out and get rid of the __sf[3] array only used for stdio file descriptors/pointers i.e. stdin/out/err I'm not using at all.
The only way I found within limited time was to remove the object module defining __sf[3] and another one referencing it from libc (libc_nano in my case).
Sure, it's a hack and not a common solution, but I had and still have no other chance to migrate to newer toolchains (I'm at GCC 13.2.1) still being able to build a specific bootloader fitting into its reserved flash sector without removing code/features from it having devices in the field.
You could manually remove findfp.o and fwalk.o from your libc analog to this example (for Windows hosted ARM cross-toolchain) targetting libc_nano (for a specific architecture):
arm-none-eabi-ar.exe -d libc_nano.a libc_a-findfp.o libc_a-fwalk.o

Or patch it out just for all architectures for release and debug libc(_nano) versions covered by the toolchain package using the mighty find GNU utility.
Invoke in your toolchain root folder (e.g. arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi):
 find . -name lib[cg]_nano.a -exec bin\arm-none-eabi-ar.exe -d {} libc_a-findfp.o libc_a-fwalk.o ;

My personal lesson learned is:
Initially try to reserve even more resources to be better prepared for future extensions and/or changes. If possible, of course.
